# publish_stream message visibility to everyone

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I use Facebook PHP API to publish to profile's news feed:

```
    $this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array(
      'message' => $msg,
      'link' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
      'privacy' => array('value' => 'EVERYONE')
    ));
```

but this message is visible only to friends. I want it to be publicly visible to everyone! Even non-friends. How to do this ?

Answer (score 4):

You, for security reasons, cannot override a user's choice on how your app posts messages.  The best you can do is to change the default visibility setting of your app (`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{APPID}/auth`) to Everyone, and then let the user change it to something else when authorizing your app.  The user also has a chance to change the setting in own settings at any time later.