# Get Visibility of app and posts level of a user using access token

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I need to get the "Visibility of app and posts" level using access token of a user who have already authorized the app using an API call. Does the FB API support this feature?

Thanks in advance.

Pubudu

Comment: Nope. You can only check for posts already made, by reading them from the API again. But the user can change their privacy settings for posts made via your app any time.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980807/publish-stream-message-visibility-to-everyone